# How to use amdgpu-pro with 17.04?

Tags: amd-graphics, 17.04, amdgpu

I tried to install `amdgpu-pro` in Zesty but encountered an error when building the kernel module:

```
Setting up amdgpu-pro-dkms (16.60-379184) ...
Loading new amdgpu-pro-16.60-379184 DKMS files...
Building for 4.10.0-13-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.10.0-13-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.10.0-13-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.10.0-13-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.60-379184/build/make.log for more information.
```

The contents of `/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.60-379184/build/make.log` are as follows:

```
DKMS make.log for amdgpu-pro-16.60-379184 for kernel 4.10.0-13-generic (x86_64)
Thu Apr 13 15:09:27 PDT 2017
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-13-generic'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.60-379184/build/built-in.o
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.60-379184/build/amd/amdgpu/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.60-379184/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.o
In file included from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.60-379184/build/amd/amdgpu/../backport/include/kcl/kcl_amdgpu.h:5:0,
                 from /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.60-379184/build/amd/amdgpu/../backport/backport.h:5,
                 from <command-line>:0:
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.60-379184/build/amd/amdgpu/../amdgpu/amdgpu.h:37:25: fatal error: linux/fence.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/fence.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
scripts/Makefile.build:294: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.60-379184/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.60-379184/build/amd/amdgpu/amdgpu_drv.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:567: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.60-379184/build/amd/amdgpu' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.60-379184/build/amd/amdgpu] Error 2
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.60-379184/build' failed
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.60-379184/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-13-generic'
```

How do I get the driver working in 17.04?

Comment: Perhaps you need to wait for an update from AMD.

Comment: 17.04 (non-LTS). `amdgpu pro` proprietary driver only supports Ubuntu LTS releases (`16.04`). It does not support non-LTS releases.

Answer (score 6):

I have some bad news.

Firstly, you're also trying to install 16.60 which is not the newest version (although the latest won't help you either).

The log file mentions:

```
/var/lib/dkms/amdgpu-pro/16.60-379184/build/amd/amdgpu/../amdgpu/amdgpu.h:37:25: fatal error: linux/fence.h: No such file or directory
```

[fence.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/fence.h) was renamed to [dma-fence.h](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.11.7/source/include/linux/dma-fence.h) in linux 4.10 (if you click on version 4.9, you'll see fence.h exists and dma-fence.h does not).

Thus, if you try the latest version ([17.10](https://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ubuntu/amdgpu-pro-17.10-401251.tar.xz) at time of writing) on a kernel 4.9 or older it *may* work... but otherwise you'll have to wait for AMD to release an update with 4.10 support.